# Querying a huge collection multiple times. Is there a more performant solution?

Tags: java, performance, collections, in-memory-database

I need you expertise on performance bottlenecks/improvements with the following code.

I have a huge collection (~2.5 million objects) of INTEREST_RATES to traverse repeatedly and fetch and return lists of fitting entries. My current solution to do this is a HSQL memory database:

**INTEREST_RATE table structure**:

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE INTEREST_RATES " +
"(EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE not NULL, "
+ "INTEREST_RATE DOUBLE not NULL, "
+ "INTEREST_RATE_CD INT not NULL, "
+ "INTEREST_RATE_TERM INT not NULL, "
+ "INTEREST_RATE_TERM_MULT VARCHAR(5) not NULL,"
+ "TERM_IN_DAYS DOUBLE not NULL,"
+ "PRIMARY KEY (EFFECTIVE_DATE, INTEREST_RATE_CD, INTEREST_RATE_TERM, INTEREST_RATE_TERM_MULT))"

CREATE INDEX dtidx ON INTEREST_RATES (EFFECTIVE_DATE, INTEREST_RATE_CD)
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT * from INTEREST_RATES where INTEREST_RATE_CD = ? and 
EFFECTIVE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE) from INTEREST_RATES 
where INTEREST_RATE_CD = ? AND EFFECTIVE_DATE <= ?)
```

--> So, I am trying to fetch the latest available RATES for a specific INTEREST_RATE_CD, giving an upper date limit.

**Java part to execute the query**:

```
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(sql);
p.setLong(1, intRateCd);
p.setLong(2, intRateCd);
p.setDate(3, someDate);

ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();
return resultSetToList(r);
```

**Java main loop using Futures/multithreading**:

```
ExecutorService executor  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
CompletionService<TestResult> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
long futureCount = 0;

while(deals.next()) //deals is a ScrollableResults set from Hibernate
{                       
    IDealEntity deal = (IDealEntity) deals.get()[0];

    //These tasks contain the INTEREST_RATE query action
    QueryTask task = new QueryTask(some params...);
    completionService.submit(task);     
}           

try 
{               
    while(futureCount < dealCount)
    {
        Future<TestResult> result = completionService.take();
        TestResult testResult = result.get();
        futureCount++;

        testResults.add(testResult);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{                   
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, 
as I try to improve the performance or find mistakes in my code, 
my questions would be:

- Could you come up with anything faster than an inmem db to repeatedly fetch objects following the query logic? Is there any better / faster / whatever data structure?

So far, HSQL was the fastest thing I could come up with. Also tried H2, which was waaaaay slower.

- Interestingly enough, my experiment using multithreading and ExecutorService doesn't really change anything performance wise.

It's nearly no difference if I use a 1 sized ThreadPool or 4 threads...

Any tipps or ideas or anything is welcome!

Comment: This probably could be a match for codereview.stackexchange.com, but not sure about it.

Comment: Anyway, in-memory operations are the most efficient. Since you have relational stuff like subqueries you *can't* use something like ElasticSearch as long as it doesn't support subqueries AFAIK. I think the only way to reduce the number of queries is to group your `deals` (in ScrollableResultSet) so that single group has identical set of parameters that would be transformed in identical query and therefore in an identical query result, that could be reused within that group of deals

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, I will think of what you're saying with further clustering! Do you have any idea why more threads won't bring better performance? I would think that 4 threads (e.g. processor cores) browsing through the RAM would be faster than 1, but no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that in memory database is good approach to solve it. Most important is to avoid full table scans. I seems to me that you have the indexes right. It would be useful to see real timings which should be milliseconds.

If this is not enough you could load whole structure in memory as nested indexed collections or hash tables and use java to directly traverse these directly.

Comment: I did a little time measuring: 35434 times query needed 290 seconds (~ 5mins), so I have about 122 calls/s. Do you think a HashMap of HashMaps would be faster? Like 1st Map having INT_RATE_CD as key, then inside there are (sorted) HashMaps having EFFECTIVE_DATE as key and containing a list of INTEREST_RATE objects?

Comment: From the times I would say the indexes are working right, if you use hashtable with interest rate as key and treemaps sorted by effective date this would be fastest, I would expect 1000 times magnitude. But think about updates.

Comment: I am currently implementing the TreeMap solution, will come back to tell how it went!

Comment: Ok, so I am done and the 35k deals are now calculated in... 1-2 seconds :) Plus, I got a little smarter - I never used TreeMaps/TreeSets before and didn't know about their features! Thanks for your help

Comment: So just 100 times faster.  If you need to be even faster, you can try to use Hashtable for INTEREST_RATE_CD. This should be fastest way of accessing data by index (except Arraylist).

Answer (score 0):

My views are that when we deal with very huge amount of data then in-memory database could create problems as it will consume very large memory unless using distributed in-memory database.

Another alternative, if not using distributed in-memory database, could be to use Cache with well suited eviction policies etc.